# how to integrate multiple sql queries using if else statement in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from emp where id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read()== true)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + "employee" + "')", true);
        }
        else if(dr.Read() == false)
            var cm = new SqlCommand("select * from student where id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader ds = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (ds.Read() == true)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + "employee" + "')", true);
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + "fulse" + "')", true);


    }
```

I am creating a system in asp.net c# which check whether the entered id represents employee or student. for that, I want to check a value from different tables on by one. I use the following code but it gives me an error.
please help to figure out where I am going wrong.
thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: it says that "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. "

Comment: You are forming your SQL queries by concatenating strings, including user input. This is a recipe for a SQL Injection Attack. Please review [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet).

Comment: i din't understand.

Comment: You don't understand what?

Comment: Injection Attack means that user could insert input which may be interpreted as query with different meaning. Just consider that user would insert something like ' OR {... delete, insert, update, literally anything ....} OR ' to your textbox

Comment: I'd also like to add that `if (dr.Read() == true) ... else if (dr.Read() == false)` will conduct two reads from your DataReader.  If that is your intent, then please ignore this comment.  The `else` clause, with no "else if" will already only fire if the initial `dr.Read()` is false.  Testing it again like that will definitely cause a second read operation.

Comment: @CodeHxr exactly, while it may be combined into single query, single read.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring second SqlCommand in

```
var cm = new SqlCommand("select * from student where id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
```

but then you're executing original one again

```
SqlDataReader ds = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

while you probably want

```
SqlDataReader ds = cm.ExecuteReader();
```

Anyway, this code has numerous of other issues as described in comments.

As first, you should fix passing of User Input as plain string. It's security must-have to use `SqlParameter` class for this.

Second, you could consider what data you're pulling from SQL Server and what you really need. As you're just interested about existence in some of table you could combine your queries into something like

```
'SELECT 1 FROM from emp where id=@id UNION SELECT 2 from student where id=@id'
```

Then you can check what number you get from SQL Server or even support scenario that ID is stored in both tables.

Third main thing is that SQL Server related operations allocates resources which are supposed to be disposed after usage. Take a look for some resources about `using` keyword in `C#` and it's combined use with types like SqlConnection, f.e.: http://nickberardi.com/proper-use-idisposable/

Comment: To add more to this answer: As far as I know you can only have one operation on a command. Calling ExecuteReader twice on the same command breaks this rule.  So following @JaroslavKadlec 's advice should resolve this issue. You probably should also dispose the command and the datareader if you have done the work